# UIPickerView numberOfRowsInComponent runs thrice

Tags: ios, swift4, uipickerview

I have a class where I am using a single pickerView for multiple textFields which works fine.
I have also set a condition `if the array that is being used for pickerView's dataSource is empty, fire a function to show an alert`. Awfully, `numberOfRowsInComponent` runs thrice and that makes the function of alert run thrice too. I am not sure why this happens.
Here are the code snippets:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    ...
    case "addExpense"?:
            if (activeTextField[0].isFirstResponder) {
                if aRR_expenseCategory.count == 0 {
                    ifArrayIsEmpty(forTextField: "category")
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return aRR_expenseCategory.count
                }
            } else if (activeTextField[1].isFirstResponder) {
                if aRR_expenseSubCategory.count == 0 {
                    ifArrayIsEmpty(forTextField: "subCategory")
                    return 0
                } else {
                    return aRR_expenseSubCategory.count
                }
            } else if (activeTextField[4].isFirstResponder) {
                return _aRR_debitedFrom.count
            } else {
                return 0
            }
    ...
}



fileprivate func ifArrayIsEmpty(forTextField tfString: String) {
        // Show Alert
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the delegate method of UITextField i.e didBeginEditing.

Inside didBeginEditing , reload your pickerView and check your dataSource and show the alert.

Comment: I did this. But I am not sure I fully understand what is going on. Because sometimes it'll work fine. But sometimes it won't, causing the keyboard/pickerview stand up constantly even after popping the VC or pushing another VC.